# Client rebalacing when leader election takes place

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a custom kafka setup, where my application and a kafka broker are placed in a single node.
To make sure that the app instance only consumes the partitions in that node(to reduce network overhead), I have a custom partition assignor assigned to all members of the group.

However, if a broker fails and then it rejoins the cluster, will that trigger a consumer re-balance ? Similarly, if I add a new broker and trigger the partition re-assignment script, would that also trigger a re-balance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a consumer rebalancing will happen when :

- A consumer joins or leaves the Consumer Group.
- A consumer fails to send an heartbeat request to the Broker Coordinator before reaching a timeout (see `session.timeout.ms` and `heartbeat.interval.ms`) managing the group.
- A consumer does not invoke the `poll()` method frequently enough (see `max.poll.interval.ms`).
- A consumer subscription has changed.
- Metadata for a topic matching the subscription has changed (i.e: the number of partitions has been increased).
- A new topic matching the subscription has been created  (when using *pattern*).
- A topic matching the subscrption has been deleted (when using *pattern*).
- When a rebalancing is manually triggered using the using Java Consumer API (see `Consumer#enforceRebalance()`).
- When the broker acting as coordinator of the group fails.

So, to answer your question adding a new broker will not trigger a partition-reassignment.

Here is blog post explaining how the rebalance protocol works [Apache Kafka Rebalance Protocol, or the magic behind your streams applications](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/apache-kafka-rebalance-protocol-or-the-magic-behind-your-streams-applications-e94baf68e4f2).